# Is (0*1*)* equal to (0 | 1)*?

Tags: state-machine, regular-language, automata, finite-automata

Are the regular expressions `(0*1*)*` and `(0 | 1)*` the same?

Could someone provide a proof or intuitive disproof for that? I feel like it is true but I’m struggling to write a step by step proof.

Comment: No they are not same

Comment: They will both match sequences of any number of 0's and 1's (including 0), but they're not "equal"

Comment: Is the first regex stronger than the second one? Can you provide an example that one regex is not able to satisfy while other does?

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera What do you mean by "stronger"?

Comment: I mean one regex represents a subset of strings of the other regex?

Comment: How about `(0?1?)*`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two different regular expressions or two grammars can generate the same languages as these do but the regular expressions or grammars are not the same. There is a standard method of constructing a non-deterministic finite state automaton from a regular expression and from that constructing a deterministic finite state automaton. That method will produce two different automata for the regular expressions in question. Though each one will recognize the same strings, they will go through different states in doing so.

Comment: Then they should represent the same language. But Code Maniac says "No they are not same".

Comment: "If two regular expressions p and q correspond to the same language then
we write p =  q , else p != q". what does `?` mean in the example(`(0?1?)*`) you provided ealier?

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera I am not sure what point you are making. So, let me clarify. We must make the distinction between a language and a grammar for that language. A given language, such as the sequence of 0's and 1's of arbitrary length, can have an infinite number of grammars (or, in this case, regular expressions, which are equivalent to regular grammars). It is these grammars that by definition are *different* although the language they recognize is the same.

Comment: Two regex are equal if their `FA`s are same? As an example `0*|1* = 1*|0*` because these `FA`s are same. Is that the point you made?

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera You wrote, "If two regular expressions p and q correspond to the same language then we write p = q , else p != q". Where did you get such an erroneous notion from? `?` in a regular expression essentially means that the regular expression that precedes it can appear 0 or 1 time (i.e. `0?` will match `0` or the empty string).

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. One last time, is it okay to write equality as `0*|1* = 1*|0*` ?

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera No, I was making the point that they were clearly different regular expressions because they had different FSAs. Even if two regular expressions that are written differently end up having the same FSAs (perhaps due to optimizations), I would still say they are different regular expressions. But they are arguably *equivalent* in the sense that they (1) recognize the same language and they are both (2) regular expressions and therefore a recognizer based upon a finite state automaton can be built to recognize that language based on either regular expression.

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera By now you should know that in my opinion `0*|1*` and `1*|0*` are different regular expressions although they are *equivalent only in the sense that they recognize the same language*.  If they look different, they are different.

Comment: +1 for making an important distinction. These regular expressions are clearly not the same - they are not equal to each other because they are clearly distinct strings of symbols. They happen to be equivalent, in the sense that the languages of these expressions are the same (equal), but that's not what was asked (perhaps it's what was meant).

Answer (score 0):

The regular expressions are equivalent.

I don't have a fully rigorous proof, but hand-waving follows.

Let `R1 = (0*1*)*` and `R2 = (0 | 1)*`. These are both regular expressions over the alphabet `A = {0, 1}`.

Part 1:

`0 | 1` is the set `{0, 1}`. `0` is an element of `0*1*` (because `0 ∈ 0*` and `ɛ ∈ 1*` and `0 ∘ ɛ = 0`) and so is `1`.

Thus `0 | 1` is a subset of `0*1*`, which means `(0 | 1)*` is a subset of `(0*1*)*`, i.e. `R2 ⊆ R1`.

Part 2:

`R2` covers all possible words over the alphabet `A`. That is, every string containing only the characters `0` and `1` is in `R2`. (This seems obvious to me; a proof probably involves the definition of `*` and/or induction.)

Therefore `R1 ⊆ R2`.

By combining part 1 and part 2 we get `R1 = R2`.

Comment: I agree that they are equivalent in the sense that they recognize the same language, i.e. the same set of strings. *But they are different regular expressions.* See my answer to the question concerning the distinction between a language and the many possible grammars and/or regular expressions for that language. You might come up with an LALR(1) grammar for some programming language such as Python but if you put it through a parser generator that requires an LL(1) grammar, you will soon appreciate the difference between the language Python and two different but "equivalent" grammars .

Comment: @RonaldAaronson This is pure math. Regular expressions don't "recognize", they generate sets of strings. And in this case they generate the same set.

Comment: @melpomene, Do you mean `R1 ~ R2` by this proof but their grammar could be different as stated by Ronald Aaronson?

Comment: Then I will say they are equivalent in that they generate the same set of strings but they do so using different "rewriting rules" along the way.

Comment: @Ronald Aaronson, Thanks again for the further clarification. melpomene, It really helps me to understand as I initially asked for a proof.

Comment: -1 while you're correct that the languages of these expressions are equal, this is not what the question is asking as currently written. If this is what Amila meant to ask, the question should be changed.

Comment: @Patrick87 I think the question itself is ambiguous. From comments like "*Is the first regex stronger than the second one? Can you provide an example that one regex is not able to satisfy while other does?*" and "*I mean one regex represents a subset of strings of the other regex?*" it seems clear to me that OP is interested in the sets of strings generated by these expressions.

Comment: @melpomene I agree that the asker probably meant to ask whether the regular expressions were equivalent, since (a) that's almost always what people want to know about different regular expressions and (b) it takes essentially no knowledge or skill to tell that the regular expressions are not *equal*; they're clearly not the same.